# How to make a d3 function as a parameter for a function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dynamic

I have a function that renders a d3 graph. But here I want to make the color dynamic taking input from front end. So parameter would an option for me.

```
function chart(colorX){

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.quantize(d3.interpolateRainbow, mainData.children.length + 2));

}
```

Here interpolateRainbow is the d3 function that I want to make as a parameter input.

if I use colorX

```
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.quantize(d3.colorX, mainData.children.length + 2));
```

it throws error.

Anyone can help me with this plz?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You have a given range of colors (for example `red` for `value: 0` and `green` for `value: 1`) and calculate a color to represent a specific value between 0 and 1 ?

Comment: I want to get "interpolateRainbow" value externally as a parameter. i.e. colorX will hold "interpolateRainbow" inside it.       I tried```  const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.quantize(`d3.${colorX}, mainData.children.length + 2`)); ```    it gives error.

Comment: `d3.interpolateRainbow` is the same as `d3["interpolateRainbow"]`. So if `colorX` is a string with the name of the color scheme, then you could do `d3[colorX]`.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Dan & Michael Rovinsky. d3[colorX] worked :)